# Transform old MacBook Pro monitor into external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

I just took apart my old MacBook Pro. I want to build from the screen an external monitor.
I know I need a controller board but I don’t know how to find the good one. Here’s a picture of the back of the screen i want to use.

Thanks, J[image]